# Run time error 1004 when trying to input hyperlinks into cells

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I seem to have no problem adding a hyperlink into one cell but when I try and add into multiple cells there is a problem. I have also tried using .formula method and writing out the =HYPERLINK formula but that encountered the same issue... any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
With Sheets(sheetName)
 .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("B1"), _
 Address:=folderName, _
 TextToDisplay:="Client"
End With

For i = 0 To lastRow - 2
    If reportRequired(i) = "Yes" Then
        fileName = folderName + "\" + clients(i) + ".docx"
        With Sheets(sheetName)
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range(Cells(i + 2, 2)), _
        Address:=fileName, _
        TextToDisplay:=clients(i)
        End With
    End If
    
Next i
```

Using the hyperlink formula I tried this way as well:

```
For i = 0 To lastRow - 2
    If reportRequired(i) = "Yes" Then
        fileName = folderName + "\" + clients(i) + ".docx"
        Sheets(sheetName).Range(Cells(i + 2, 2)).formula = "=HYPERLINK(" + fileName + """ + clients(i) + """ + ")"
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Use `Anchor:=.Cells(i + 2, 2)` instead of `Anchor:=.Range(Cells(i + 2, 2))`

Comment: Perfect thank you!!:)